# Infinite Limits at Infinity

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^3-4x+1}{2x^2+2}=\infty$.
I am having trouble proving this question. You must use the limit definition for infinity. That is given any N>0 , there exist an M>0 such that if x>M then f(x)>N

Comment: Oh sorry should be 3x^3 instead of 3x^2

Comment: It has to be proven using this limit definition. For any N>0, there exist an M>0 such that if x>M then f(x)>N

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$
\frac{3x^3-4x+1}{2x^2+2} = \frac{x^3}{x^2}\cdot\frac{3-\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}}{2+\frac{2}{x^2}}
$$
and look at the behavior of the two factors when $x$ goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Factor the greatest power of $x$ from both numerator and denominator. Then cancel $x$'s from both. You get the result.

Answer (score 1):

$3x^3 - 4x + 1 > 2x^3$, and $2x^2 + 2 < 3x^2$ when $x > 10$. So: $\dfrac{3x^3 - 4x + 1}{2x^2 + 2} > \dfrac{2x}{3}$ when $x > 10$. But $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{2x}{3} = +\infty$. So $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{3x^3 - 4x + 1}{2x^2 + 2} = +\infty$

Comment: but what is your N. since you have to show f(x)>N

Comment: How do you know x>10

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing both numerator and denominator by $x^a$ (with $a$ a well chosen number) and see what happens.